# how to Freez the report headers in an RDLC report?

Tags: rdlc

I am making RDLC reports in visual studio 2013. the data source for the reports is Entity Framework collections.
I want to Freeze the report headers so that if the user scrolls vertically then the rows might move but the column header should not hide. it should always be on the top of the rows.

Something similar to Excel Freeze panes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tablix Properties and check "Keep header visible while scrolling" [image]